# Clasp throws 'Syntax error: Missing ; before statement' on including most node libraries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, clasp

I'm trying to parse HTML and XML elements and for that I included popular libraries like Cheerio and node-html-parser but on including them clasp throws Syntax error: Missing ; before statement error and I can't seem to find way around it.

```
errors: [
    {
      message: 'Syntax error: Missing ; before statement. line: 9175 file: code-3.12.0',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

Code at line 9175:

```
var NodeType;
(function (NodeType) {
    NodeType[NodeType["ELEMENT_NODE"] = 1] = "ELEMENT_NODE";
    NodeType[NodeType["TEXT_NODE"] = 3] = "TEXT_NODE";
})(NodeType = exports.NodeType || (exports.NodeType = {}));
/**
 * Node Class as base class for TextNode and HTMLElement.
 */
class Node {
    constructor() {
        this.childNodes = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Google introduced support for the V8 runtime in [February 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#february_5_2020) allowing [classes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#classes).

---

[Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) don't exist in Google Apps Script. Apps Script is [based on JavaScript 1.6,](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) which is from [2005](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6), but classes were introduced in [2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html). You would have to convert the class to a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes).

If you were to switch to TypeScript, you could use [clasp's built-in conversion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/typescript).

There are other ways to try automating the conversion. You'll have to find what works best for you (e.g. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

Comment: I'm using Babel and Webpack.

Comment: @Eru Then I think you need to review the configuration. `class Node {}` will fail in Apps Script, so pushing it will result in an error.

Comment: How do you suggest should I got about it? I'm afraid I'm still a newb at babel and webpack configuration and the I'm currently using a preconfigured starter from https://github.com/labnol/apps-script-starter.

Comment: @Eru Sorry, I really don't have much experience with those tools. I suggest that you  amend your question (or post another) with your Babel configuration and add the `babeljs` tag.